# Paginating a collection from DB receiving updates

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I need to serve elements sorted on a particular field (`score`) to a client in a paginated fashion.

The elements are stored in MongoDB as part of a collection. One document looks like this:

```
{
    "id": ObjectId("<>"),
    "score": 10
}
```

To serve the elements, I reverse sort the documents on the `score` field, and serve 10 elements to the client.
Also, the value in the `score` field is continuously getting updates from another consumer in an async fashion.

How can I perform pagination of such documents? I was thinking about the following approaches that I usually use, but cannot find a way to fit them in the above design:

1. Return the last served score as offset and in the next request to fetch elements use the offset. 
   **Issue**: This would return some duplicates with the same score (as many elements can have same scores).

Comment: If your records are frequently (how frequently? per second / minute / hour?) updating, then what is the point of doing pagination sorted by score? IMO, you can show top ten just for kinda monitoring purposes. Other wise, if frequency is  very high, you won't be able to meaningfully paginate over such collection. Also you have to consider, how many of such records will you have. If it is 10s or 100s, and objects are not very large, it might be reasonable to do periodic `findAll()` and return to client all the data, and / or paginate over that frozen / cached periodic snapshot.

Comment: There is not fixed frequency of updated, but we can assume they're happening every 2-3 minutes. The score is actually the performance of a particular element, and the client needs to display the top performing elements to the user (kind of like top-rated/most-viewed video/image).

Showing top ten is a good solution for the prototype, but eventually all the elements will have to be served.

The number of elements can be a lot, so I might not be able to load everything into memory.

Comment: Then it is all related to your business requirements. First draft them, how it should be visible by user, who is user etc. Think the edge possible cases. For example, suppose list of items with page size of 10, if it takes 3-5 minutes for user to read before advancing to next page, then can it be that while user reading those 10 items, they become next 10 items? Then as per business needs, draft the technical requirements. May be it is unnecessary to have such frequently updated list, so delay updates to 15 / 30 minutes intervals if pagination needed. Or may be pagination not needed at all.

Comment: You business requirements can drift your technical requirements from very simple, like show only top 10, to as complex as persistent cursors, where on the time of initial request, you are snapshot-ing user specific cursor for some validity period, and refresh the cursor once it is expired. All business dependent. In pagination, there is no good or bad solutions, usually all solutions are bad :) Depends on how convenient it for the user :)

Comment: True, makes sense. But technically, using persistent cursors to build such a mechanism sounds like a good idea.